# Best way to make a Side Panel UI with Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, gui, hud

Take this image for example, the game is called Realm of the mad god, and it has this side panel filling the whole screen height with the player info.

To reproduce it, Is there any way to make the game "view" smaller so I can fit the side panel to its right without literally overlaying the game, PROBABLY like this game did, or is the only way out to overlay the game?

(Tibia might also be an example of a game smaller then its UI)

[image: Side Panel example]

Comment: This looks like a job for a viewport. [It looks like libgdx's version has a "right gutter width" property that would be useful here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html#getRightGutterWidth--).

Comment: Oh thank you Gregory! Sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 1):

"This looks like a job for a viewport. It looks like libgdx's version has a "right gutter width" property that would be useful here" - DMGregory found it!

Comment: This answer would be even better if you included a code sample to show how you used this property in your game to achieve the effect you wanted.