# Having GUI on side rather than on game screen

Tags: opengl, java, gui, lwjgl, mouse

[image: Screen with GUI]

[image: Screen without GUI]

How would I make it so that rather on the game screen the GUI is on the side of the screen and puts the game screen in its own little area so that its not covering part of the screen because right now it takes up part when the area should be like the bottom one where you can see the whole thing..... but have the GUI menu thingy there as well because also right now if you click where the GUI menu thingy is just pretends its not there so right now its just basically an image on the screen and sense the game uses mouse when clicking in the GUI menu thingy it shouldn't move the player either...... So how would I put them in there own little areas....? Also right now the whole games screen size is 1100 by 800 and the area for the game screen will be 675 by 799... also the location of the GUI menu thingy on the top screen is where it will be.....

Comment: We had a [similar question a while ago using LibGDX](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/183570/39518), but the core concept of setting a viewport should be similar in lwjgl.

Comment: I looked at it and it says something about a viewport.... I don't know what that is......

Comment: Then your next port of call was your favourite search engine, entering keywords like ["OpenGL viewport"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=opengl+viewport&ia=qa) to fix that, right?